# JAXB Error while using in SpringREST to return a ArrayList of a domain object

Tags: spring, annotations, jaxb

I am trying to use JAXB in Spring RESTful webservice.
My code is as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/countries",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
 public @ResponseBody CountryList getCountry() {
  logger.debug("Provider has received request to get all persons");

  // Call service here
  CountryList result = new CountryList();
  result.setData(countryService.getAll());

  return result;
 }
```

The CountryList.java class looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="countries")
public class CountryList {

 @XmlElement(required = true)
 public List<Country> data;

 @XmlElement(required = false)
 public List<Country> getData() {
  return data;
 }

 public void setData(List<Country> data) {
  this.data = data;
 }
}
```

The Country.java looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="country")
public class Country {

    private Calendar createdDt;
    private String updatedBy;
    private String createdBy;
    private Long id;
    private String countryName;
    private Calendar updatedDt;

// getters and setters for all attributes goes here 

}
```

Now, when I access the method getCountry(), I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "data"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List com.cisco.bic.services.model.CountryList.getData()
        at com.cisco.bic.services.model.CountryList
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List com.cisco.bic.services.model.CountryList.data
        at com.cisco.bic.services.model.CountryList
```

Would anyone has any idea why is this error coming. Am I doing anything wrong in the annotaion part ??

Please help.

Regards 
Saroj

Comment: Could we see your spring configuration?

Comment: I have found this article very useful in the past: http://java-diaries.blogspot.com/2011/02/restful-webservices-with-spring.html

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanx a lot for your reply. I have changed my annotation as per the example given in the link http://java-diaries.blogspot.com/2011/02/restful-webservices-with-spring.html and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Changed my CountryList.java as follows and it worked fine:

@XmlRootElement(name="countries")
public class CountryList implements Serializable{
   
    /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1431094580954491617L;
 private List<Country> countries;
   
    public CountryList(){}
    public CountryList(List<Country> countries){
        this.countries = countries;
    }
   
    @XmlElement(name="country")
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
    public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
}

Comment: Great. I found that article to be the best one out there for getting a quick web service up and running with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't annotate both the getter/setter and the field, you need to decide on one of them.